# How to find highest of 3 columns using DAX calculated column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm writing a calculated column to return maximum of 3 columns:

```
HighestOf3Cols =
return if(and(Sale[col1]>=Sale[col2],
Sale[col1]>=Sale[col3]),
Sale[col1],
if(Sale[col2]>Sale[col3],
Sale[col2],
Sale[col3]
    )
)
```

1. Is the correct way to write simple DAX logic?
2. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated columns should be avoided in DAX. They are static and slow the development down (every model change requires each calculated column to be re-evaluated and so adding a new measure after a while becomes very slow). If it is a static column you require, I would do this in Power Query and simply use List.Max().

If you insist on DAX, I would write it like this:

```
Column = MAX( MAX('Table'[Column1], 'Table'[Column2]), 'Table'[Column3])
```

Comment: Or MAXX if writing measure?

Comment: Depends if you need a measure or a column and your wider requirements.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to do it in the **Power Query Editor**. Just select all columns you wants and add a step to get the maximum value in a new column-

[image]